# How can I validate the azp claim?

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Considering the following jwt token:

[image]
I use the following code to protect my aspnet core webapi:

```
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(jwtBearerOptions =>
    {
        configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", jwtBearerOptions);
    },
    microsoftIdentityOptions => { configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", microsoftIdentityOptions); });
```

How can I add validation to above code to validate the `azp` calim?

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [Policy-based Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to achieve this. In your case, a simple [function policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy) should help check the `azp` claim.

By default, you need to use this policy in `Authorize` attributes on your controllers, pages, or endpoints. Since you might want this for all endpoints,
you could add it as an [authorization filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0#require-authenticated-users).